# XSL copy mixed content

Tags: xml, xslt

I didn't really find the solution to my problem although I guess it's probably not hard at all, so bear with me.

How can I copy mixed Content with XSL?

For example I have something like this:

```
<root>
    <element>
        uvw <child>abc</child> xyz
    </element>
</root>
```

And I just want to copy the inside of `<element>`, so my output should be

```
uvw <child>abc</child> xyz
```

(it is allowed in the element I want to put it at)
I tried

```
 <xsl:copy-of select="element/text()"/>
 <xsl:copy-of select="element/child"/>
```

But it resulted in:

```
 uvw xyz <child>abc</child>
```

and I tried:

```
<xsl:value-of select="element"/>
```

which resulted in

```
 uvw abc xyz
```

and I tried a few other things that apparently weren't valid, so I won't go into that. Any ideas? I read and read and I just don't get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select all child nodes of the `element` element use `element/node()` e.g. `<xsl:copy-of select="element/node()"/>`.

Comment: Ha, so simple, I knew it must be something really easy. Thank you.